# Disable connection to Databases in @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, testing, configuration

So, I'm now making integration tests, and I want to exclude anything database realated (the repositories will be mocked). Also, I connect to 2 databases, so all in all I have:

- An application.yml with 2 database properties
- A FirstDatabaseConfiguration class with `@Configuration`
- A SecondDatabaseConfiguration class with `@Configuration`

I tried (and worked before, when using just 1 database, configuring it in the application.yml, without the 2 java configuration classes) to do this:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Like I said, I remember it working with 1 database, but now with 2 it just doesn't. The problem that I'm seing is that it's trying to load the `@Bean`s from FirstDatabaseConfiguration and SecondDatabaseConfiguration.

It's also of note that I'm using profiles. In main, I have a `application-dev.yml` with database secrets, and in test I have a `application-test.yml` with other secrets. Recently, because of this problem, I added the database secrets there too but without actual values, just blank strings (`""`).

With that and removing the `@EnableAutoConfiguration(...)` part, I don't have the bean problem, and it fails when trying to connect to the database (of course). But it doesn't stop the execution of the tests, so I'm running with it for now.

It's far from ideal, so I want to ask: how can I make a `@SpringBootTest` while excluding database configurations? It seems so easy to exclude `@AutoConfiguration`s, but it isn't that easy for `@Configuration`s. If only I could exclude `FirstDatabaseConfiguration` and `SecondDatabaseConfiguration`, then with the `@EnableAutoConfiguration(..)` setup I showed before I should be fine (maybe?).

src/main/resources/application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  mvc:
    pathmatch:
      matching-strategy: ant_path_matcher
  datasource:
    clients:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:sqlserver://${secrets.db.clientes.host}:${secrets.db.clientes.port};databaseName=${secrets.db.clientes.database};TrustServerCertificate=True;
      username: ${secrets.db.clientes.user}
      password: ${secrets.db.clientes.password}
      driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      hikari:
        read-only: true
    nexos:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:sqlserver://${secrets.db.nexos.host}:${secrets.db.nexos.port};databaseName=${secrets.db.nexos.database};TrustServerCertificate=True;
      username: ${secrets.db.nexos.user}
      password: ${secrets.db.nexos.password}
      driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      hikari:
        read-only: true
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

configuration class (the two are basically the same):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.example.demo.repositories.client",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "clientEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "clientTransactionManager"
)
public class ClientesDatabaseConfiguration {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "clientDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.clients")
    public DataSource clienteDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "clientEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean clienteEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                                                                              @Qualifier("clientDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");

        return builder
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .properties(properties)
            .packages("com.example.demo.db.client")
            .persistenceUnit("clients")
            .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "clientTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager clienteTransactionManager(@Qualifier("clientEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

test:

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class IntegrationTests {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by mocking the beans of the database that I did not want enabled.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).